# iOS Collapse/ Expand Sections by clicking another section in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a question about making a table view section expand/collapse. There are many pieces of information on the web about this topic, but my question is a little bit different.

My question is, **how can I make an additional section when the user taps on another section?**

The following images may help you understand my situation.

[image]

At the top of the table view we have one small section (section 0).

If I tap it...

[image]

Section 1 and 2 should be created between section 0 and 3.

How can I do this? Is there any way or code? Please help me.

Also, I tried this code but got a sigabrt error :(

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
    indexSet.add(indexPath.section + 1)
    indexSet.add(indexPath.section + 2)

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if expandCol == true {
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: 2) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
            expandCol = !expandCol
        } else {
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: 2) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
            expandCol = !expandCol
        }
    }

    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/InfinityExpandableTableTree

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a flag variable on view-controller for `selectedSection`.

```
var selectedSection: Int = -1

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == selectedSection ? <section-row-count> : 0
}
```

Set the flag value in section header action method:

```
func actionSectionHeader(tag: Int) {
    selectedSection = tag
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a new section into `UITableView`, you need

1 - Update your data. For example, insert your sections in a data array, or change their visibility flags.

2 - Call the following method.

```
tableView.insertSections([1, 2], with: .automatic)
```

or

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

The first method will update your `UITableView` with an animation. The second one will update it instantly. For better UX I'd recommend you to use the first one.

**Update on your code**

At first, you can pass all sections indices at once using a simple array. Like that

```
if expandCol {
    self.tableView.deleteSections([1, 2], with: .automatic)
} else {
    self.tableView.insertSections([1, 2], with: .automatic)
}
expandCol = !expandCol
```

The second problem is that you're calling `reloadData` after you call the animated update of your table.

And the most important, you **need to change the data**. You `UITableView` has a `dataSource` and it returns a number of sections and cells. After user interacts with your trigger cell, you need to make changes at that data before calling the update.